# Editing events in Fullcalendar with modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm trying to edit objects with a modal Bootstrap. I've got that if you click over an event in Fullcalendar a form comes up with the info of that event (level,day,period) so I can edit the level and the day of that event(object). The problem is that when I click in the bottom save a new object is created instead of editing that event. Can't I get the params of the event clicked and change them??

This is my javascript where I set the eventClick function.

```
var y = "y";
function drawControl(controls) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            contentHeight: 500,
            scrollTime: '24:00:00',
            minTime: '01:00:00',
            maxTime: '24:00:00',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header:{left:"prev,next,today",
            center:"title",
            right:"month, agendaWeek, agendaDay"},


            events: allControls(controls),

            eventRender: function(event, element) {

                var bloodLevel=event.title

                if(bloodLevel >= 180) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
                else if(bloodLevel < 70) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    x=calEvent.id;
                $('#modalTitle').html(calEvent.title);
                $('#control_day_edit').val(calEvent.start);
                $('#control_level').val(calEvent.title.toString());
                    console.log(calEvent.title)
                    console.log(calEvent.start._i)
                    console.log(calEvent.id)
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href',"/users/:user_id/controls/calEvent.id/edit");
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                y=calEvent;

            }
})
}
```

});

```
document.getElementById('button_edit').addEventListener("click", editControl);

 function editControl(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log(x);
     var controlEdited = {
         "level": document.getElementById('control_level').value,
         "day": document.getElementById('control_day_edit').value,
         "period": document.getElementById('control_period').value,
         "id": x
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', y);
    $.post("/editControls", JSON.stringify(controlEdited));

    console.log(controlEdited)

};
```

This is the code of my controller

```
def editControls
    if request.xhr?
        @control = JSON.parse!(request.body.read.to_s)
        Control.where(id: @control["id"])[0].update_attributes(level: @control["level"], day: @control["day"], period: @control["period"])
        render json: "ok"
    else
        return error
    end
end
```

This is the code of the view

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
            <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
          <%= render 'form_edit' %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"><a id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the form

```
<% modal ||= false %>
<% remote = modal ? true : false %>
<div class="">
<%= form_for [@user, @control],remote: remote, html: {role: :form, 'data-model' => 'control'} do |f| %>
    <p class="new_control_text">Edit Control</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.label :level, class: "sr-only"%>

          <%= f.number_field :level, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter level" %>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group container">
        <div class="row datetimeselect">
            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>

                        <%= f.text_field :day, default: @control_day, :class => 'form-control', id: "control_day_edit" %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>

    <div class="select_period">
       <%= f.select :period, options_for_select([['pre-breakfast'], ['post-breakfast'],['pre-lunch'],['post-lunch'],['afternoon'],['pre-dinner'],['post-dinner']]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>      

      <a href="#" id="button_edit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button">
            Save
      </a>

<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: where is  your save code (i.e. you need to show us what you are doing inside the modal in order to save the changes)?

Comment: Ok. I've edited the question with the form modal

Comment: @DavidDsr, how do you pass from rails to js the :user_id in this line?: $('#eventUrl').attr('href',"/users/:user_id/controls/calEvent.id/edit")

Answer (score 0):

In your `eventClick` you have access to the `calEvent` object. You need to [update](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) this object to see it properly reflected in the calendar. Check out more of the event data methods in the [fullCalendar docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/)

Comment: But I need to update not only the client side but the server side as well. I think I might do it with a post ajax

Comment: Of course, but even after the ajax update you have to use the `calEvent` object and the fullCalendar method for updating that object to see the change render in the calendar.

Comment: I've added $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event); in the code but is not editing that event but is creating another new when I click save in the modal form. I've updated the question to you can check it out.

Comment: you might have to do a `removeEvent` and then `addEvent`

Comment: I've added $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', calEvent._id ); but it doesn't remove the event.

Comment: the id must off, try `console.log` the `calEvent` object to see what it looks like, maybe the id method is just `id` instead of `_id`

Comment: Ok, I have created an anchor with a role button and I've put an addEventListener on it. So when I click in that anchor send a post with the new information. The thing is that in the server is ok, the control stores ok the new information, but in the client side, when I click save the event doesn't update at that moment, but if I refresh the page the event is updated propperly. I think the key could be in the $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', y); I've had to create var y because function editControls is out of eventClick

Answer (score 0):

Your original `event object` has all the data inherent to your `fullcalendar` event. So you need to first get a hold of that object, then assign new values to the attributes you might want to change, and finally call the calendar with a with the `"updateEvent"` instruction.

The `"updateEvent"` reports changes to an event and renders them on the calendar.

```
.fullCalendar( 'updateEvent', event )
```

event must be the original `Event Object` for an event, not merely a reconstructed object. The original `Event Object` can obtained by callbacks such as `eventClick`, or by the `clientEvents` function.

Here is how you might update an event after a click:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event, element) {

        event.title = "CLICKED!";

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

    }
});
```

Source: [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/)

Comment: this only works because you have the event object passed in the eventClick function. Once you open a modal for editing though the event object is out of scope so you can't call updateEvent from the modal

Comment: @botheredbybees I did put the Documentation link where you can read more info. Read the anwser: "So you need to first get a hold of that object". I have this implementation running myself exactly with a modal. I do not understand what scope you are talking about. Please, remove the negative vote.

Comment: Hi Alejandro, I'm not sure you've read through the original code. The calendar isn't displayed on the modal, it's on the original page and the modal is displayed when an event on the calendar is clicked. Each of the fields in the modal is loaded but the event object is not directly available to the modal, which is why David saved a pointer to the object in the global variable: y
Your solution is not allowing any user editing of the event's fields in a modal

Comment: @botheredbybees I did read it. That's why I wrote my answer, to use a "pointer" to the object. My solution can edit an event. Sorry, I don't understand you. Maybe you are confusing my code with the OP code: mine is a generic code to ilustrate the point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the event global.
Create a global variable

```
var evnt
```

Then within the fullcalendar click event give that variable the value of the event object.

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {//click en un evento
        evnt = calEvent;
//more actions
}
```

Then you have the event available for update in your modal or other function

```
function event_update(){
evnt.title = 'new title';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', evnt);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you pretty much nailed it, you just needed to update the event object stored in the global y variable before calling updateEvent:

```
document.getElementById('button_edit').addEventListener("click", editControl);

 function editControl(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log(x);
     var controlEdited = {
         "level": document.getElementById('control_level').value,
         "day": document.getElementById('control_day_edit').value,
         "period": document.getElementById('control_period').value,
         "id": x
    }
    y.start = document.getElementById('control_day_edit').value;
    y.title = document.getElementById('control_level').value;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', y);
    $.post("/editControls", JSON.stringify(controlEdited));

    console.log(controlEdited)

};
```